# MATLAB: Datenum format mismatch

Tags: matlab

I was working to convert a table of strings to a datenum object using MATLAB 2010a.

```
>> datenum('01-Jan-11', 'dd-mmm-yy')
??? Error using ==> datenum at 182
DATENUM failed.

Caused by:
    Error using ==> dtstr2dtnummx
    Failed on converting date string to date number.

>> datenum('02-Jan-11', 'dd-mmm-yy')

ans =

      734505

>> datenum('03-Jan-11', 'dd-mmm-yy')
??? Error using ==> datenum at 182
DATENUM failed.

Caused by:
    Error using ==> dtstr2dtnummx
    Failed on converting date string to date number.
>> datenum('04-Jan-11', 'dd-mmm-yy')

ans =

      734507
```

I am not able to understand the reason for this error. Can any one please elaborate?

Comment: In my case using MATLAB R2014a and Win7, `datenum('01-Jan-11', 'dd-mmm-yy')` works and returns `734504`. You could have a look the documentation for R2010a by typing `doc datenum` and check if something is different there.

Comment: The documentation states that:

Convert a date string to a serial date number using the default pivot year:
n = datenum('12-jun-17', 'dd-mmm-yy')

n =
      736858

Comment: I have tried with MATLAB R2013a and the same system. It works perfectly fine.

Comment: `dtstr2dtnummx` is unfortunately a MEX function.  It could simply be a bug in the actual MEX code, and that you can't fix it unless you upgrade your version of MATLAB.

Answer (score 0):

I already see this problem at matlab2010, but didn`t find at Matlab2015. This sounds be a old bug

if you call again datenum('01-Jan-11', 'dd-mmm-yy') you will see that the second try this will work even if the first time didn`t work.

The only way to work around with this was puting a try catch statement and puting the datenum again at catch. This worked very well at my case.

Try to do this

try
datenum('01-Jan-11', 'dd-mmm-yy');
catch
datenum('01-Jan-11', 'dd-mmm-yy');
end

This will work for you